# How can I render a WPF Grid that has 14 equal sized columns and 1 column 30% the size of the previous equal columns

Tags: c#, wpf, grid-layout

I have a grid that is being overlayed an image. A user will input the total image length and width in meters. They will also input the size of the columns and rows they want.
For example the image is 143 meters long and 216 meters wide, and they want the grid cells to be 10 meters wide by 15 meters high.
So I would need 14 equal width cells and 1 cell that is 30% the width of the previous 14. I am adding the columns through a loop

```
        numColumns = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(143 / 10));
        numRows = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(216 / 15));
        for(int i = 0; i < numColumns + 1; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
            if(i == 0)
            {
                col.Width = new GridLength(gridHeaderOffset);
            }
            else if(i < numColumns)
            {
                col.Width = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Auto);
            }
            else
            {
                col.Width = new GridLength(Math.Round( (143 % 10), 2), GridUnitType.Star);
            }
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is some where in the 2nd last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetupGrid(143);
        }

        private void SetupGrid(double width)
        {
            LayoutRoot.ShowGridLines = true;
            int numColumns = Convert.ToInt32(width / 10);
            double remainder = width % 10;
            //create whole columns
            for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
            {
                ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
                col.Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star);
                LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
                //adding a textblock just so show the placement
                TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
                t.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                t.Text = i.ToString();
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(t);
                Grid.SetColumn(t, i);
            }
            //create remainder
            ColumnDefinition colr = new ColumnDefinition();
            colr.Width = new GridLength(remainder, GridUnitType.Star);
            LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colr);
            //adding a textblock just so show the placement
            TextBlock t2 = new TextBlock();
            t2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            t2.Text = remainder.ToString();
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(t2);
            Grid.SetColumn(t2, numColumns + 1);
        }
```